# chinese remainder theorem problem in one of the steps

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to calculate the following:

$$x=8 \pmod{9}$$
$$x=9 \pmod{10}$$
$$x=0 \pmod{11}$$

I am using the chinese remainder theorem as follows:

Step 1:

$$m=9\cdot10\cdot11 = 990$$

Step 2:

$$M_1 = \frac{m}{9} = 110$$

$$M_2 = \frac{m}{10} = 99$$

$$M_3 = \frac{m}{11} = 90$$

Step 3:

$$x=8\cdot110\cdot2 + 9\cdot99\cdot9 + 0\cdot90\cdot2 = 9779 = 869\mod 990$$

I have used online calculators to check this result and I know it is wrong (it should be 539 I think) but cannot find out what am I doing wrong. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$x \equiv -1 \pmod 9$ and $x \equiv -1 \pmod {10}.$ So $x \equiv -1 \pmod {90}$ and $x = 90 n - 1.$ But $90 = 88 + 2,$ so $90 \equiv 2 \pmod {11}.$

$$ x = 90 n - 1 \equiv 2n - 1 \pmod {11}. $$
$$ 2n \equiv 1 \pmod {11}, $$
$$ n \equiv 6 \pmod {11}. $$
Start with $n=6,$ so $x = 540 - 1 = 539.$

$$ \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc   \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

A more official way to combine the $90$ and $11$ parts is this: the continued fraction for $90/11$ has penultimate convergent $41/5,$ and
$$ 41 \cdot 11 - 5 \cdot 90 = 1. $$
So 
$$ 451 \equiv 1 \pmod {90}, \; \; 451 \equiv 0 \pmod {11},  $$
$$ -450 \equiv 0 \pmod {90}, \; \; -450 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}.  $$
We want something $-1 \pmod {90}$ and $0 \pmod {11},$ so we can ignore the second pair and use
$$ -451 \equiv -1 \pmod {90}, \; \; -451 \equiv 0 \pmod {11}.  $$
Also note
$$ 990 - 451 = 539. $$

Let's see: the virtue of the continued fraction thing is that, when i want something $A \pmod {90}$ but $B \pmod {11},$ I just take $451 A -450 B.$

Answer (score 0):

Start solving the first two congruences: a *Bézout's relation* between $9$ and $10$ is $\;9\cdot 9-8\cdot 10=1$, hence
$$\begin{cases}m\equiv\color{red}{8}\mod9 \\ m\equiv \color{red}{9}\mod 10\end{cases}\iff m\equiv\color{red}{9}\cdot 9\cdot 9-\color{red}{8}\cdot8\cdot 10=\color{red}{89}\mod 90 $$
Now solve for
$\begin{cases}x\equiv\color{red}{89}\mod90, \\ m\equiv \color{red}{0}\mod 11.\end{cases} $

We might proceed the same, from a Bézout's relation, but it is simpler, due to the value $0\mod 11$, to consider it means $\;89+90k$ is divisible by $11$. Now
$$89+90k=88+1+88k+2k\equiv 2k+1\mod 11, $$
so it means $2k+1$ is an odd multiple of $11$, e. g. $k=5$. Thus we obtain tha basic solution:
$$x=89+5\cdot 90=\color{red}{539}.$$